# Статуя (фигура) аллегории Изобилия... все слова на своих местах?

Tags: словосочетания

> Сцену утверждения проекта иллюстрирует рельеф на фонтане слева, над
>   статуей аллегории Изобилия.

Ну я прежде никогда не встречала статуй аллегорий...

> Эта сцена запечатлена на мраморном рельефе фонтана Треви – между
>   двумя колоннами справа, над фигурой аллегории Целительства.

Если *можно* не править, *нужно* не править!

СПАСИБО!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сцену утверждения проекта иллюстрирует рельеф на фонтане слева, **над аллегорией Изобилия.** Эта сцена запечатлена на мраморном рельефе фонтана Треви – между двумя колоннами справа, **над аллегорией Целительства.**

**Пояснение**

**Из словаря:** АЛЛЕГОРИЯ, в искусстве **воплощение какой-л. идеи в конкретных художественных образах и формах** (скульптурах, героях литературных и живописных произведений и т.п.). **Минерва** в живописных полотнах классиков ― аллегория мудрости.

Фигура, статуя ― это аллегории какой-то идеи (Изобилия и т.д.), н**о нельзя сказать: фигура аллегории, статуя аллегории.**